# How To Add Preflight Missing Allow-Origin Header In Kubernetes Gateway API

Tags: cors, google-kubernetes-engine, gcp-load-balancer, kubernetes-gateway-api

We are leveraging the power of Kubernetes Gateway API to use it capabilities in Gateway and HTTPRoute.

We have a simple Gateway resource that uses a GKE External Global LoadBalancer. Below shows  the full manifest code

```
kind: Gateway
apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: external-http
  namespace: infra-ns
spec:
  gatewayClassName: gke-l7-global-external-managed
  listeners:
  - name: https
    protocol: HTTPS
    port: 443
    allowedRoutes:
      namespaces:
        from: Selector
        selector:
          matchLabels:
            shared-gateway-access: "true"
    tls:
      mode: Terminate
      options:
        networking.gke.io/pre-shared-certs: ipos-cert
  addresses:
  - type: NamedAddress
    value: "l7lb-external-ip-address"
```

This Gateway is attached to multiple HTTPRoutes like so

```
rules:
- matches:
  - path:
      value: /api/v1/service  
  backendRefs:
  - name: example-service
    port: 80
```

The setup work well when requests are sent from code application clients. The problem is if request is sent through browser, we get a `Cross-Origin Resource Sharing error: PreflightMissingAllowOriginHeader` and request status says `CORS error`

How can we add the missing Allow Origin Header using `Kubernetes Gateway API`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CORS support is on the GKE Gateway roadmap, but for now you will need to add support from within your application backend.

Comment: Your reply have saved me hours of frustration and waste

Comment: hi @YunusEinsteinium i have the same issue and i am using a simple hhtp connection and golang gin framework, can you give advise on how to solve this as i am thinking to try ingress and leave gatewayAPI

Comment: @Sam add CORS at application level

Comment: thank yunus i had my issue in another part which i added as an answer if someone is getting issues with this as it took me time and your question shows first when searching for gke gatewayAPI issues

Answer (score 0):

I want to add my side on how i solved this issue as Gari Singh said you have to do it in application level which i did and i tried a lot of implementations but none worked, only by chance when i saw the GKE cluster logs and there was an issue in health checks that is implemented by default by GKE gatewayAPI i had to configure my service to send a 200 ok status as a respond to /GET request, you can see this in official docs [gatewayAPI Restrictions and Limitations](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/deploying-gateways#limitations), the part we are interested in is

> GKE Gateway behaves differently than Ingress, in that Gateway does not infer health check parameters. If your Service does not return 200 for requests to GET /, or you have other tuned pod readiness checks, you need to configure a HealthCheckPolicy for your service.

The context is if your back-end service is not healthy the traffic will not be sent to it so all requests from frontend to backend will report a CORS error.
so i hope this saves someone time who may not be an expert like me.